# Recyclerview notifyDataSetChanged(); not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have tried to delete the items from RecyclerView and update the list again using below code

```
public class ScannedCodesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScannedCodesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<CodeItem> mList;
private Context mContext;
private OnItemClickListener mClick;

public ScannedCodesAdapter(List<CodeItem> list, Context context, OnItemClickListener click) {
    mList = list;
    mContext = context;
    mClick = click;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ScanProductCodeItemBinding mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
            R.layout.scan_product_code_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(mBinding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    CodeItem item = mList.get(position);
    String code = item.getCode();
    holder.binding.adapterCode.setText(code);
    int num = position + 1;
    if (mList != null)
        holder.binding.adapterNum.setText(num + " ");
    if ((position % 2) == 0) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.color2);
    }

    if (item.selected) {
        holder.binding.adapterDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.binding.adapterDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        for (CodeItem m : mList) {
            m.selected = false;
        }
        item.selected = true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
    holder.binding.adapterDelete.setOnClickListener(view ->
    {
       // mClick.onClick(view, position);
        //notifyItemRemoved(position);

        SQLiteDataBaseHandler handler = new SQLiteDataBaseHandler(mContext);
        CodeItem codeItem = handler.getCodeItem(code);
        if (item != null) {
        handler.deleteCode(codeItem);
         notifyDataSetChanged();
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ScanProductCodeItemBinding binding;

    public ViewHolder(ScanProductCodeItemBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }
}
```

in here recycler not updating after delete the item. 
If I go back and come only update the list. also I tried OnItemClickListener to remove from the activity. 
 notifyDataSetChanged(); I tried this and also I tried notifyItemRemoved(position); but not working 
Anyone suggest the idea to do this ??

Comment: Does your handler.deleteCode(codeItem); update the mList? Can you add the code for deleteCode method.

Comment: public void deleteCode(CodeItem codeItem) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CODE, KEY_CODE + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(codeItem.getStatus())});

 
        db.close();
    }

This is the code for delete the item

Comment: See my answer below. since your mList is not changing your notifyDataSet will not work. For it to work your list that populates the adapter should change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you need to update your code. Based on your `deleteCode` method your mList is not getting modified on delete. `notifyDataSetChanged` only works if the underlying list that populates the adapter changes.

So you need to update your `mList` before calling `notifyDataSetChanged`

So modify your code as -

```
holder.binding.adapterDelete.setOnClickListener(view ->
{
    //Remove from list
    mList.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
     //...delete from db ...
    SQLiteDataBaseHandler handler = new SQLiteDataBaseHandler(mContext);
    CodeItem codeItem = handler.getCodeItem(code);
    if (item != null) {
    handler.deleteCode(codeItem);

});
```

Comment: Yeah thanks @kapsym, I didn't remove the item in the list in this case.

Comment: @AngelJanniee great. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
holder.binding.adapterDelete.setOnClickListener(view ->
    {
        //Remove from list
        mList.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
         //...delete from db ...
        SQLiteDataBaseHandler handler = new SQLiteDataBaseHandler(mContext);
        CodeItem codeItem = handler.getCodeItem(code);
        if (item != null) {
        handler.deleteCode(codeItem);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data `List<CodeItem> mList` isn't modified before `notifyDataSetChanged` call. Remove appropriative item from the list before `notifyDataSetChanged` call.